# Buttons in Google+ Plus. Where is the .js function called?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-plus

Today I started to discover the HTML Code of Google+

When I inspected the Buttons like "start Hangout", I can't see the function where the javascript code is called. Look here:

```
<div role="button" class="d-s-r tk3N6e-e tk3N6e-e-qc a-b-kh-fs a-kh-fs-e" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none; ">Start a hangout</div>
```

there is no onclick() function.

Any ideas how it works? Perhaps a Observer for the Button state? is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are probably binding the function in an external js file to the id or class selector.

I don't believe they use jQuery (but they very well may), but this is how you would do it in an external js in jquery:

```
$("#id").click(function() {
  //run onclick code
});
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is also arguably the "right" way to make HTML elements respond to user events.  I wouldn't hire a front end developer that uses "<div onclick='foo()'>` in their code test :(

Comment: Learning never stops. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the functional aspect of the code is being defined in a separate javascript file. For examples of this, you can check out the [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function of jQuery.